# How to ensure PivotCache is working properly?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot in Excel via VBA, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this code isn't working. It's not throwing any errors - there just isn't a pivot table being created. I've used this exact same code in other programs without issue (obviously replacing the local variables). I've already confirmed that my source data is correctly defined. My only lead is that after executing the creation of the pivot cache, it's showing that PvtCache = Nothing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Create_Report()

Dim sht_Break_Data As Worksheet
Dim sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt As Worksheet

Dim tab_name As String
Dim lrow_Src As Long
Dim lcol_Src As Long

Dim rng_Pvt_Source As Range
Dim PvtStart As Range
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache
Dim Pvt As PivotTable
Dim PvtField As PivotField
Dim PvtName As String

    Set_Global_Variables

    'Get last row and column of Source Data Tab
    With sht_Source_Data
        lrow_Src = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol_Src = .Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Set source data range for pivots
        Set rng_Pvt_Source = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lrow_Src, lcol_Src))
    End With

'=======================================Create Pivot for Number of Breaks==========================================='
    'Create sheet for Number of Breaks Pivot
    'If the given tab name already exists, contents are deleted. If not, it is created
    With ThisWorkbook
        tab_name = "Num of Breaks Pivot"
        If SheetExists(tab_name, ThisWorkbook) = True Then
            Set sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt = .Sheets(tab_name)
            On Error Resume Next
            sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt.ShowAllData 'clear any active filter
            sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt.Cells.Delete 'delete content
            Else
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = tab_name 'add new tab to the end
            Set sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt = .Sheets(tab_name)
        End If

        'Define pivot start location
        Set PvtStart = sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt.Cells(2, 1)

        'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
        Set PvtCache = .PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=rng_Pvt_Source)

        'Create Pivot table from Pivot cache
        Set Pvt = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
            TableDestination:=PvtStart, _
            TableName:="test")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a hunch: step through the code line by line using F8, and check that  sht_Num_Breaks_Pvt is being set to the sheet you think it is.

Comment: Already checked by printing the name of the sheet, and it's correct.

Comment: Okay. Can you add this to end of the routine, and post back about what comes up?
msgbox pvt.parent.name & " " & pvt.name

Comment: Nothing will print since the PvtCache isn't being set (for whatever reason). I gave in and eventually just modified output from the macro recorder to get it to work. See my answer for that.

Comment: I hadn't noticed until now that you have an On Error Resume Next statement. It's not generally good practice to have this without a closing On Error Goto 0 as any subsequest errors will be masked, which is what is happening here. Can you elaborate why you need the On Error Resume Next statement at all? What happens if you comment it out?

Comment: I have it because trying to `.ShowAllData` will result in an error if there's no active filter on the data. But you're right, I overlooked adding an `On Error Go To 0` after that line.

Comment: So if you put an On Error Go To 0 in, what line is the original code throwing an error on?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above code to work, no matter how much sense it makes. So, I just decided to use the recorder and modify the output. Here's some working code:

```
    'Create pivot for Breaks w/o Remedies >30 days
    .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        rng_rmdy_GT30.Address(, , xlR1C1, True), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=sht_rmdyGT30_Pivot.Cells(2, 1), _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    sht_rmdyGT30_Pivot.Activate
    Set Pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
```

Oddly enough, not having the source data range in R1C1 format broke this code as well.